# Angular 6: How to bundle a script into a library project?

Tags: angular

I'm developing a library for one of my projects and I was wondering if I can embed one of its dependencies in the library itself. I'm aware that I can simply declare it as a peerDependencies which I'll eventually do but I want to embed it if possible.

Let's say for example, If I'm create a library that has a jQuery plugin based component in it, So I want to embed relevant .js file to it like we do in a normal project using angular.json. I tried to do this within library project but it throws an error like "Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(styles)."

I don't know if its possible or not. Can anyone suggest how it is supposed to be done please.

Thanks much!